# JavaFX - ListView item not selected upon Initialization

Tags: java, listview, javafx, javafx-8

Hi all I have a fairly odd question regarding the initialization of a Scene in JavaFX that contains a ListView.

The issue is that when I initialize a scene for my program I want the first item of a ListView to be selected. However, if I am able to select it (through odd means mentioned later on) the ListView itself is not in focus. What I want to happen is that the first item in the ListView is selected **and** the ListView being in focus.

I'll start with minimal code to try and illustrate my issue:

```
public class SceneSetter {

static Stage mainStage;
static Scene adminScene;
static AdminController adminCont;

public static void initialize(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    mainStage = stage;

    FXMLLoader adminLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    adminLoader.setLocation(SceneSetter.class.getResource("/view/Admin.fxml"));
    SplitPane adminRoot = adminLoader.load();
    adminScene = new Scene(adminRoot);
    adminCont = adminLoader.getController();

    goToAdmin();
}

public static void goToAdmin() {
    mainStage.setScene(adminScene);
    //adminCont.initialize();
    mainStage.show();
}
}
```

My original program has multiple scenes that all need to be set upon the program starting. So within this SceneSetter class all those scenes are set and the controllers added in. I have removed those as this bit of code is able to demonstrate the issue.

My admincontroller is as follows:

```
public class AdminController {
Stage mainStage;
private ObservableList<User> userList;

@FXML
private ListView<User> userListView;

@FXML
private Button adminAdd;

public void initialize() {
    userListView.setItems(Admin.getUserlist());
    userListView.getSelectionModel().select(0);
    userListView.getFocusModel().focus(0);
}

public void setMainStage(Stage s) {
    mainStage = s;
}
}
```

The problem here is that when I run my code the item that I want to be selected is either:

1. Not selected
2. Not in Focus

My confusion is compounded bc of the following. If in my SceneSetter class, in my goToAdmin methods the commented line of code `adminCont.initialize()` is kept commented the program appears as follows:

[image]

When I uncomment the same line of code, the program appears as follows:

[image]

In the first instance, the correct item is not even selected. In the second, the ListView is not in focus.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to focus a control you need to request it. The method you are searching for is `requestFocus()`. But there is a catch. Reading the JavaDoc :

> To be eligible to receive the focus, the node must be part of a scene,
>   it and all of its ancestors must be visible, and it must not be
>   disabled

So that means you have two choices.

- You could call the `requestFocus()` inside a `Platform.runLater()` in order to be sure that the scene graph have been created.
- You could call the `requestFocus()` after you added the control on the Scene.

Example :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SceneSetter extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage mainStage) throws Exception {
        ListView<String> list = new ListView<String>();
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Single", "Double", "Suite", "Family App");
        list.setItems(items);

        list.getSelectionModel().select(0);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                list.requestFocus();
            }
        });

        mainStage.setScene(new Scene(list));
        // or here 
        // list.requestFocus();
        mainStage.show();
    }

}
```

An example with FXML file

**Main** :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SceneSetter extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage mainStage) throws Exception {
        ListView<String> list = FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("GUI.fxml"));

        mainStage.setScene(new Scene(list));

        mainStage.show();
    }

}
```

**Controller** :

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;

public class MyController {

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> userListView;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Single", "Double", "Suite", "Family App");
        userListView.setItems(items);
        userListView.getSelectionModel().select(0);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                userListView.requestFocus();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way for the ListView to come in focus within the Controller class? We have multiple scenes within Scene Setter so I do not think having the above will be helpful for all scenes in the Scene Setter class.

Comment: Also, if at all possible. The question touches how having this line: adminCont.initialize() commented/uncommented changes behavior. Any idea why?

Comment: First have you tried to wrap the `requestFocus` inside a `Platform.runLater()` call of course on the FXML file? If so what was your result? Now about the the commented code all I can tell is that you missed a `@FXML` annotation on the initialize method.

Comment: Thank you so much. The `Platform.runLater()` fixed it for me. However it only works when I have the `adminCont.initialize()` uncommented in the `goToAdmin()` method. I tried adding the FXML tag and it did not help. This answer is for the all intents and purposes, correct. So if you can't work out what the issue is there - I'll still approve the answer. Would just be appreciated.

Comment: Check my edit above. Are you sure we have the same `initialize()` method? If so then the error is somewhere else. It's almost 4am here so I might not see it :P,

Comment: I have the same initialize method. The issue persists however - if I do not call the initialize method twice the first field will not be highlighted. I have verified the answer as this is fine, I'm just confused.

Comment: If you could, I would like to see the complete code ( cause i can't compile the example above ) and of course make any changes as i said ( ex the missing @FXML annotation)

Comment: Calling the jfxlistview.requestFocus() inside the Platform.runLater() is throwing undefined for me. Can anyone help?

Comment: @David This post is 3 years old it would be a bad idea to edit it and mix things up. I would suggest to create a new post specifying your requirements and the java version you are using. The above example still works for JDK 1.8.